# Failed compiling sass file

Tags: css, node.js, npm, sass

I have an error when I try to compile with the command line

```
$ npm run compile:sass
```

> natours@1.0.0 compile:sass C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Ministere de l'Enseignement Superieur et de la Recherche Scientifique\Bureau\Natours
>   node-sass sass/main.scss css/main.css

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "file": "C:/Users/user/OneDrive - Ministere de l'Enseignement Superieur et de la Recherche Scientifique/Bureau/Natours/sass/main.scss",
  "line": 1,
  "column": 1,
  "message": "File to import not found or unreadable: abstracts/functions.",
  "formatted": "Error: File to import not found or unreadable: abstracts/functions.\n        on line 1 of sass/main.scss\n>> @import \"abstracts/functions\"; \r\n   ^\n"
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! natours@1.0.0 compile:sass: `node-sass sass/main.scss css/main.css`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the natours@1.0.0 compile:sass script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-16T23_28_59_364Z-debug.log
```

[image]

Comment: `File to import not found or unreadable: abstracts/functions` Have you checked that?

Comment: Yes I checked that but the same problem throws